# How to have both Xcode 7 and Xcode 6 installed

Tags: xcode

I would like to try out Swift 2.0 while being able to continue to develop my apps(which is still at 1.2 at the moment)
Going to the Mac App Store shows "Update", so I assume it'll overwrite my xcode?

Any ideas?

Comment: You can download current and old versions of Xcode directly from Apple's developer website without going through the App Store. https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply rename your Xcode in Applications folder to `Xcode_6` and then install `Xcode 7`.

Please read [similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/974015/is-there-a-way-to-run-xcode-6-and-7-side-by-side) with a little different approach.

Comment: WARNING: this strategy works for the Xcode 7 betas, but for the Xcode 7 release version it blows away any other older versions - I lost my old Xcode 6 (renamed) due to this earlier this week - make sure you have backups !

Comment: So is it really impossible?

Comment: I've edited my post with reference to a similar post cracking this issue. Please take a look.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried downloading from the link in the thread that you linked? Cause with my 20Mbps network, the download keeps getting stuck at 0.0Kbps, I tried using Safari + firefox + chrome and it's the same result. Just want to know if the problem is from my side.

Comment: @Happiehappie No, I did not :). Perhaps I will in faster network. Right now, network strength is not good for me.

Comment: Alright, the download is picking up, I'll let you guys know the result ;)